# How can I send useful Stackoverflow articles to my Kindle?

Tags: kindle

I love stackoverflow and I love my new [Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/kindle) and I'm looking to bridge the gap.

Anybody devised a clever way to do this?

Disclaimer: Yes i know this is not technically a programming question but theres always so many things on here I want to read but want to do it out by the pool and not at my desk :-)

Comment: stackoverflow.uservoice.com ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RekindleIt ( http://www.rekindle.it/ ) is also a service to send a current page to the Kindle device.

Comment: don't have my kindle on me right now but the mechanism by which this works looks exactly what i need

Answer (score 8):

http://Instapaper.com has great kindle support and http://www.kindlefeeder.com/ has rss support.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently created [ebooks of the top 20 tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74399/stack-overflow-top-20-tags-in-ebook-format) in Mobipocket format designed for the Kindle.

The code uses the monthly data dump to pick the top articles and the source is available on Github if you want to tweak it for your own use.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Send to Kindle](http://www.klip.me/sendtokindle/). Actually being enlightened by this question, latest version of "Send to Kindle" adds support for Stackoverflow and Quora.

:)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has their own [Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle/chrome) extension for Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

You can read RSS using Google Reader. It allows [off-line reading](http://www.google.com/help/reader/offline.html).

http://thepugetnews.com/2008/04/29/using-google-reader-on-the-amazon-kindle/

Comment: Surely offline reading requires GoogleGears which is unlikely to be ported to the Kindle?

Comment: Actually, hasn't the off-line mode been withdrawn now due to lack of use?

Answer (score 0):

I'm now on an iPad and using POcket (formerly read it later)